# jQuery Tablesorter and sortList

Tags: tablesorter

I am using the jQuery tablesorter plugin (http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html)

The tablesorter is working and I can disable sorting and filtering on a column using this code.

```
// Disable sorting and filtering on 1st column
$("table thead th:eq(0)").data("sorter", false).data("filter", false);
```

How can I use the .data method to do the equivalent of this?

```
$("table").tablesorter({ 
// sort on the 4th column, order asc 
sortList: [[3,0]] 
});
```

My problem is I can't determine how to use sortList: [[3,0]] with .data syntax. Any recommendations will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use the data function like this to update the saved sort, but then you would need to actually trigger a sort to apply it:

```
$("table").data('tablesorter').sortList = [[3,0]];
$("table").trigger('update'); // apply the new sort
```

But really I think your best bet would be to just trigger a `sorton` event:

```
$("table").trigger("sorton", [[3,0]]);
```

Comment: Mottie - Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting an error "data is null or not an object"

Comment: I can only guess that the error is from using the first snippet. Just make sure tablesorter is initialized before using it.

Answer (score 0):

"sorton event" like this

```
$("table").trigger("sorton", [[[3,0]]]);
```